# fill multiple textbox on button click

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, textbox

i have two winforms, Form1 & Form2,  on form1 i have a button which when clicked opens Form2 as a Dialog, am using f2.ShowDialog() method. now, i want that when form2 opens, then all the textbox controls are filled with some specified text , which is extracted from a sql table, or from a datagridview on form1. for this am using:

```
f2.Controls["StudentName"].Text= datagridview1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
f2.Controls["StudentClass"].Text= datagridview1.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
f2.Controls["StudentSection"].Text= datagridview1.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
f2.Controls["StudentMobile"].Text= datagridview1.SelectedCells[3].Value.ToString();
```

But, this doesn't seems good, because am having 10 textbox controls on form2 , so this is just not a programming way of doing it....please guide me to some efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a corresponding Tag to the gridview cell, so **datagridview1.SelectedCells[0].Tag** whould be "StudentName".
Then you can:

```
foreach(var cell in datagridview1.SelectedCells){
   try
   {
       f2.Controls[(string)cell.Tag].Text= cell.Text;
   }
   catch
   {
        //Whatever you want
   }
}
```

Or you could have associated column names of the datagrid with your f2 controls.

It is not the most beautiful way, but it is instant and it just works .

Comment: then for, studentclass , studentmobile, the tag will have to be assigned values?

Comment: @MajesticRa:Does Tag gives the column name?

Comment: Tag is just a container where you can hold any object (derived from object) you want. In this case I suggest you to use strings to identify how to bind each particular cell to a field.

Comment: @MajesticRa:i have edited some errors, its ---datagridview1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();

Comment: datagridview1.SelectedColumns[0].Name - will give you the column name

Comment: @MajesticRa: so if i want to send the data from a datagridview on form1 to form2, then i will have to use Tag, it will hold the data?

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to be a good candidate for a ViewModel to bind your control properties against. Then you can update the model in response to actions on the dialog or from database queries and the UI will update.

Comment: or you can use WPF binding, dependency property can help

Answer (score 0):

Using the `FindControl()` get the required text from the datagridview, any how the code you have written has some mistakes, how can it be all the selectedCells's text will be assigned from a same control at a time?